# Where is the very last egg in Spyro: Year of the Dragon?

Tags: spyro-year-of-the-dragon

At the end of the game, when you have found every egg in every world, and beaten the final boss, twice. It still shows one more egg to be found. What am I missing?

Gems are showing full completion. **I am not interested in bonus eggs that do not show up under normal completion**. I am posting for a friend, and they literally just want to fill the standard completion requirements.

Comment: How many eggs and gems do you have in total?
have you been to the "Super Bonus Round"?

Comment: @MrDeanosupreamo, I can not recall what the "Super Bonus Round" is, but gems are showing 100%.

Comment: Where have you challenged the Sorceress the second time? Because you need to defeat her in the *Super Bonus Round* too, after the first classic way.

Comment: I have the same issue, 148/148 eggs but the last world needs 149 eggs to open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original releases of the game there is a bug with the egg reward from any of the 4 speedways. Sometimes you are not rewarded with an egg after winning the race/time attack.

This may explain why you are missing an egg. Unfortunately it is not easy to remedy.

The Greatest Hits, Collector's Edition and Platinum versions will not have this bug and additionally they are the solution to fixing your save file. Load your save game on one of these versions of the game and you will be instantly rewarded with your missing egg.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, because OP said he has found every egg in every world.

Comment: I agree, however this might be the case for someone else.

Comment: This actually matches the requirements a lot closer then pinckermans answer. Will have to double check, but its starting to sound like it has, in fact, bugged out.

Comment: If this is true, shouldn't you see a missing egg for that level (Honey Speedway usually)? If so, the sentence "when you have found every egg in every world" is misleading.

Comment: I have clarified that the final egg would show **before** allowing the player to enter the secret world. I believe my friend has encountered a bug very similar to the one you describe, where she has collected the egg, but it simply does not show in the final completion. Im not a fan of find the bug questions, so Im just going to accept this answer.

Comment: @Timelord64 yeah lots of people get this, worse that all 4 speedways and all races are affected by this bug, increasing the chances of encountering it quite a lot. It's good that there is a fix for it though. You just need to get your hands on one of those newer releases, ask your friends or loan it from a store or something. Hopefully you can get the final egg without starting over.

Comment: @Aequitas you don't need it for speedway bug. You can teleport to Super Bonus Round by using the code "Up, Down, Up, Down, Left, Right, Left, Right, Square, Down, Circle" at pause screen and progress shows up in atlas. No "Greatest Hits" needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just beaten the Sorceress boss for the first time, then you probably miss [The Super Bonus Round](http://spyro.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Bonus_Round), the final realm in *Spyro: Year of the Dragon*.
You can enter it after you've collected all 15,000 gems and 149 Dragon Eggs from the other realms. The portal to this realm can be found in [Midnight Mountain](http://spyro.wikia.com/wiki/Midnight_Mountain), a short glide away from the *Harbor Speedway*.

In this level you can find 5000 extra gems and the very last egg you miss.

After that you should have 150 eggs and a 117% completion percentage.

Comment: If this is not the case, how many eggs do you have? Can you post a screenshot of the missing egg in your Inventory?

Comment: i should have just answered:P

Comment: @MrDeanosupreamo LOL just seen your comment

Comment: ahahaha love it

Comment: OP said he had 100% gems so this is probably not it since you said there are 5k gems here

Comment: @Aequitas but those gems are extra gems, the Inventory counts only the basic game, you can get 117% completion of the game with that level.

Comment: @pinckerman ah okay fair enough then, sounds likely that this is their missing egg then.

Comment: Wouldnt that imply that the egg would also not show as normal completion?

Comment: @Timelord64 Technically you're right, but that extra egg has the purpose of letting you know about that secret level, imho. Anyway, have you found the *Super Bonus Round*?

Comment: For the third time, The sorcoress has been defeated twice. And again, since that egg doesn't come under 100% completion, **even if it did not reward the egg correctly, it is not the egg I am looking for**

Comment: @Timelord64 is it possible to see a screenshot of your Inventory that shows this missing egg?

Comment: Once I have it available to me, again

Comment: I can confirm that **the atlast displays a total of 148 eggs**. If you require 149 eggs to enter the secret level your so confident holds my friends missing egg, **they must be missing an egg BEFORE the secret level, or they have encountered a bug**. So yes, Aequitas' answer does come far closer to answering the question for me.

Comment: @Timelord64 Ok, fair enough. Yes, there are a total of 149 eggs. If your friend can't find a missing egg in any level from the Atlas, it must be the Speedway bug.

Answer (score 1):

The 149th egg is hidden behind a breakable wall in midnight world. It is marked as "Shh its a secret".